# Multidimensional array - replace

Tags: php

I have an array, similar to the following:

```
$array = [
    ['file' => 1, 'status' => 'pending'],
    ['file' => 2, 'status' => 'pending'],
];
```

What I want to do is to replace the `status`part, where the `file` is `1`

I'm not sure if i can do this in a simple array, or using an in-built `array_` method

I have something liek the following so far:

```
$data = [];
foreach($array as $arr => $val) {
    if ($val['file'] == 1) {
      $data['status'] = 'updated';
    }
}
```

Comment: Iterate through the top level of the array with a foreach loop, and treat each item in the foreach as a dictionary and check the `item["file"] == 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, but as `$data` is array of arrays, you need to provide `$arr` as top-level key and even get rid of second array:

```
foreach($array as $arr => $val) {
    if ($val['file'] == 1) {
        $array[$arr]['status'] = 'updated';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This will replace the `status` value. But I then need to update the main multidimensional array with this value

Comment: What is __main multidimensional array__?

Answer (score 0):

This should give you an idea of how to tackle that.

```
 if ($array[0]['file'] == 1) {
                $array[0]['whatever'] = $array[0]['status'];
                unset($array[0]['status']);
            }
```

The 0 can ofcourse be changed by **i** in a loop if you wish to cycle through the entire array.